# Angular and HTML: Programatically create HTML table rows based number of items in an Angular $scope var

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Currently I am using Angular to populate the data in an HTML table. Right now I am manually coding each row for display, however, I am searching for a solution to programmatically define each html row. The Angular controller below is simplified as I am using a for loop to populate many rows of data.

Is there a programmatic html solution to define each of these rows?

HTML

```
 <tr>
    <td>{{oneCategory}}</td>
    <td>{{oneDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{oneNote}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="rowOne in one">{{ rowOne.value }}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>{{twoCategory}}</td>
    <td>{{twoDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{twoNote}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="rowTwo in two">{{ rowTwo.value }}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>{{threeCategory}}</td>
    <td>{{threeDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{threeNote}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="rowThree in three">{{ rowThree.value }}
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Angular Controller

```
 var row2wordOBJ = {0: 'one', 1: 'two', 2:'three', 3: 'four', 4:'five', 
 5:'six', 6:'seven', 7:'eight', 8:'nine', 9:'ten', 10:'eleven', 11:'twelve'}

 var objKeys_responseData = Object.keys(response.data)
 // outer loop controls the object key pointer                                                                                                                                      
 for(a=0; a < objKeys_responseData.length; a++){
 var objKey = objKeys_responseData[a]
     for(b=0; b < response.data[objKey_responseData].length; b++){
         var row = row2wordOBJ[b]
         $scope[row + 'Category'] = response.data[objKey][b].category
         $scope[row + 'Desc'] = response.data[objKey][b].desc
         $scope[row + 'Note'] = response.data[objKey][b].note
         $scope[row] = response.data[objKey][b].value
      }
  }
```

**EDIT**

Second Solution Also Provided By Nitin Walia. The final logic will depend on how you need to control the display on the html table data. Both answers will work.

Angular Controller

```
$scope.item1 = response.data[key1]
$scope.item2 = response.data[key2]
```

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in item1">
    <td>{{data.category}}</td>
    <td>{{data.oneDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{data.note}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="val in data.value">{{ val.value }}</td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="data in item2">
    <td>{{data.category}}</td>
    <td>{{data.oneDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{data.note}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="val in data.value">{{ val.value }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you include the code that populates these rows?

Comment: the code for ng-repeat?

Comment: The for loop that creates your rows that you mentioned in your post. It would help to know what pattern is used to create your rows.

Comment: What is one , two , three of you ? Can you provide full code of it

Comment: @ThanhTùng  values for one, two and three updated

Comment: @ TahTatsumoto Updated to the controller to show how the html is being populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try ng-repeat

angular

```
$scope.item =[];
   for(b=0; b < response.data[objKey_responseData].length; b++){
     $scope.item[b].category  = response.data[objKey][b].category
     $scope.item[b].Desc = response.data[objKey][b].desc
     $scope.item[b].Note = response.data[objKey][b].note
     $scope.item[b].value = response.data[objKey][b].value
  }
```

/////////
   HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in item">
    <td>{{data.category}}</td>
    <td>{{data.oneDesc}}</td>
    <td>{{data.note}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="val in data.value">{{ val.value }}</td>
 </tr>
```

EDIT to fix the undefined error do this..

```
$scope.item =[];
   for(b=0; b < response.data[objKey_responseData].length; b++){
     var itemObj = {
       'category'  : response.data[objKey][b].category,
       'desc' :response.data[objKey][b].desc,
       'Note' : response.data[objKey][b].note,
       'value': response.data[objKey][b].value
     }
     $scope.item.push(itemObj);
  }
```

Comment: how do you modify your answer with the value as an array of objects? Here is an example:   [{value:1}, {value:2}, {value:3}]

Comment: in your answer on the controller side, you use $scope[b]. shouldn't you use $scope.item[b]?

Comment: just pass the array object of values in $scope.item[b].value

Comment: there is an error in your soln. I keep getting --> Cannot set property 'category' of undefined

Comment: try this change 
$scope.item =[];   to $scope.item = {}

Comment: Dude your first answer was right on the money. it just took me a second to understand your logic.

Comment: fixed the undefined error check my edit in answer if you found this helpful give thumbs up